# What are the reasons to use "syscall" instead of calling the function directly?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

There's [syscall](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html) which allows indirect system calls in Linux. What are the reasons to use it - and why is it better than direct call to the function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometimes the kernel adds system calls and it takes a while for the C library to support them.

Or maybe you are compiling on an old Linux distribution, but want to run on a newer one.

Example code:

```
// syscall 277 is sync_file_range() on x86_64 Linux.  The header
// files lack it on scc-suse10 where we compile, but the
// performance benefits are substantial, so we just call it
// directly.  FIXME someday.
#define SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE 2
    syscall(277, fd, done, n, SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE);
```

But in general, there is no advantage to using `syscall` if the C library in your compilation environment has what you need.  (For one thing, it is even less portable than using a Linux-specific interface, since the system call numbers vary by CPU.)

Comment: They shouldn't vary by CPU, only by operating system implementation.

Comment: @Wug: The actual syscall numbers vary on x86, x86_64, ARM, PPC, etc.

Comment: That would be operating system implementation.  They're not dependent on the CPU in any way, they're defined in a header somewhere and compiled into the kernel.

Comment: @Wug: The question is about the Linux "syscall" function, whose "operating system implementation" varies by CPU.  Thus "the system call numbers vary by CPU" is a perfectly accurate statement.