# when to use syscall function instead of c lib wrapper

Tags: c, system-calls

I was looking at the `libevent` code, and saw some code like this:

```
 int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event) {
        return (syscall(__NR_epoll_ctl, epfd, op, fd, event));
 }
```

What are the reasons to use it? Why would this be better than a direct call to the function?

```
 int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);
```

Comment: See [this post to stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285969/what-are-the-reasons-to-use-syscall-instead-of-calling-the-function-directly)

Comment: notice that that library *defines* the `epoll_ctl` symbol that is has the same name as in `glibc`; it is probably guarded by something like `#if LIBC_DOES_NOT_PROVIDE_EPOLL_CTL`

Comment: thank you very much, understand it.