# What are the arguments of syscall (2) and their purpose?

Tags: c, linux, x86, x86-64, system-calls

I came across this [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux) which shows that there can be 7 arguments passed to `syscall`, and I want to understand what is the purpose of each one of them.

This is not specified in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).
Also, I have found a [table](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) of the arguments you can pass to each syscall but I don't necessarily understand the common ground between them.

Ideally, I'm looking for an answer that specifies

```
arg #1 - pid  
arg #2 - ...
```

Architecture is x86-64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [table you linked to](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) provides the list of arguments you're asking for.

I think what may be confusing you is that `syscall` doesn't perform a single operation. Rather, it's a general-purpose API for *anything* you might want to ask the kernel to do -- open a file, map memory, fork a new process, and so on.

The specific operation you want the kernel to do is selected using the syscall number. Just picking the first one from the table, syscall 0 (known as `sys_read`) reads from a file.

Obviously, the operations performed by the different syscalls require different arguments. Staying with the `sys_read` example, we see in the table that it takes three arguments: The file descriptor (`fd`), a pointer to a buffer (`buf`) and a number of bytes to read (`count`). So if you wanted to call this syscall, you would do it as follows:

```c
#include <sys/syscall.h>

// Assuming these have been initialized appropriately.
unsigned int fd = ...;
char * buf = ...;
size_t count = ...;

syscall(SYS_read, fd, buf, count);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286108/134877) has more information on when you might want to choose to use `syscall`. The short version is that the reasons to use `syscall` are few and far between.

Edit: As @PeterCordes points out, syscall numbers differ between ABIs, so you should use the constants defined in `sys/syscall.h` instead of hardcoding syscall numbers yourself.

Comment: The answer you linked in the last paragraph describes when you'd want to use the `syscall(int, ...)` wrapper function in C.  Not the `syscall` *instruction* to inline a syscall in asm.  If you're playing around with toy programs and not linking libc, you usually want to use syscall directly.

Comment: @PeterCordes: is there a `syscall` instruction? On older time we used `INT`, later `ENTER`, and now I think just a `JMP` (no real address, selector table of "segment" has the data on which ring and which kernel address to execute)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Yes, AMD introduced [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall), and reworked it for AMD64.  It's the only way to use the 64-bit system-call ABI from user-space on Linux.  It's not plausible that `enter` could be used for system calls - it's a slow way to make a stack frame; perhaps you're thinking of `sysenter` (Intel's 32-bit fast-system-call instruction)?  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) for the difference and an example of using Linux `write` both ways.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Re: `jmp` - what?  Perhaps you're thinking of 32-bit Windows DLLs that call into 64-bit code with a far jmp or call, instead of having the kernel support a 32-bit ABI natively (like Linux does).  That doesn't enter the kernel, though.  (I think you *could* configure the GDT with a call gate or something that would make a far `jmp` or `call` enter the kernel, but I don't know of any mainstream x86-64 OS that does that instead of using the much faster `syscall`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The OP links to the man page for the `syscall(2)` wrapper function, so I assume they're asking about that, not the `syscall` instruction.

Comment: @MartinB: Oh, you're right, this is tagged `[x86-64]` but *not* `[assembly]`, and has `syscall(2)` in the title.  We get many questions about the `syscall` instruction, and the OP's first link was about assembly language.  In the tags I follow I've basically never seen one like this, and I skimmed too quickly to notice I was making a wrong assumption >.<

Comment: Since you're giving a portable answer, you don't want to hard-code the call numbers - they differ between ISAs, even between i386 and amd64.  Use `__NR_read` or `SYS_read` after including the appropriate headers (`<asm/unistd.h>` or `<sys/syscall.h>`).  `__NR_read` is 0 on x86-64, but not on i386.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, that's a great point -- I've edited the answer accordingly.